# Is this sentence correct "For me, I think programming is as a fun activity than be a job." (grammar and meaning)

Tags: grammar, meaning

Is this sentence correct

> "For me, I think programming is as a fun activity than be a job."

Should I use be or beeing?
Is using than correct here?

And if the sentence wrong how can I say it?

Comment: Welcome.   The sentence is not correct as written.   Do you mean to say, "**I think programming is *more* fun as a hobby, *than* it is as a job**", or "**I think programming is *equally* fun as a job or a hobby**"?

Comment: @whiskeychief thanks a lot. I want to say that I look to my job "programming" as entertainment like playing video games and I don't look at that just like a job. I think this one  "I think programming is more fun as a hobby, than it is as a job" is my mean.

Comment: OK!  Then you are pretty close.  "I find programming to be entertaining, and I don't look at it as **just a job**".   Or,  "I find programming so entertaining, I don't see it as **just being a job**".   Or,  "Programming is so fun for me, I don't feel like it's **only a job**."

Comment: @whiskeychief  Thank you so much. I think this "I find programming to be entertaining, and I don't look at it as just a job" was what I want.

Comment: OK!  I guess I will add this as an answer below which you can *accept* using the green checkmark if you agree.

Comment: Ok. I will mark it as answer after you added it. thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sentence is not correct as written. It could mean:

> - "I think programming is **more fun** as a hobby, **than** it is as a job", or
> - "I think programming is **equally fun** as a job **or** a hobby"

To express that you enjoy programming **more** for fun than as a job, you'd say one of these:

> - "I find programming to be entertaining, **and** I don't look at it as just a job".
> - "I find programming **so** entertaining, I don't see it as **just** being a job".
> - "I find programming **so** entertaining that I don't see it as **just** being a job".
> - "Programming is **so** fun for me, I don't feel like it's **only** a job."

If you use "so", then you are creating a comparison -- "just" or "only" completes the thought.  Enjoy!